# What is the difference between enabling Build App Bundle in Unity and enabling Build App Bundles in Unity Cloud Build?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mobile, build, build-settings

I'm currently working on an Android app build and have some questions about making the .aab file.

I read [this page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859348?hl=en&visit_id=637637472134192779-1040756559&rd=1) and I usually generate the apk file but I'm trying to create the Android App Bundle this time. I saw people add a checkmark to the Build App Bundle section in Unity, but I also found there is the Build App Bundles section in the advanced options of Unity Cloud Build. I hadn't realized that I've added a checkmark to both of the section until other people told me, but in this case, do I just need to enable one of the Build App Bundles in Unity and Unity Cloud Build? Why I should not add checkmarks to both of the sections? (sorry if it's a dumb question)

Am I right by enabling Build App Bundle in Unity just creates ".aab" file and I can use the file in UCB when uploading the app to Google play, on the other hand, by enabling Build App Bundle in UCB uses ".apk" file which was generated in Unity project with Build App Bundle disabled, and the ".aab" file created in UCB is applied when the app is uploaded to Google Play?

I was told that other people can only download the ".apk" file, and I guess that's because I enabled both of the Build App Bundle in Unity and UCB. (please correct me if I'm wrong...)

Answer (score 0):

The config in Unity Cloud Build overrides project settings when starting the build. There's no difference between the checkmarks you mention, it's just that the option chosen in Unity Cloud Build is the one that is relevant when you build on UCB.